# SqlException: Invalid column name 'c' on project migrated from core 2.0 to 2.1

Tags: c#, asp.net-core-mvc, asp.net-core-2.0, asp.net-core-2.1

I migrated my project from .net core 2.0 to .net core 2.1 , i changed the libraries according to the documentation. My whole project is working fine but only my question module is giving
[this error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DU1pz.png).

my controller queries works fine when i debug it, i think there is an issue in paginatedList but i have no idea how to resolve it.

Here is my controller function that is being executed.

```
 public async Task<IActionResult> Index(string sortOrder, string currentFilter, string searchString, int? page)
    {
        ViewData["CurrentSort"] = sortOrder;
        ViewData["NameSortParm"] = String.IsNullOrEmpty(sortOrder) ? "name_desc" : "";
        ViewData["DateSortParm"] = sortOrder == "Date" ? "date_desc" : "Date";
        ViewData["CurrentFilter"] = searchString;

        //Check User Profile is complete or not 
        var user = await _userManager.GetCurrentUser(HttpContext);
        var userPersonalRow = _context.UserPersonalDetail.Where(a => a.UserId == user.Id).SingleOrDefault();
        if (userPersonalRow == null)
        {
            return RedirectToAction("CompleteProfile", "Home");
        }
        var questionList = (from question in _context.UserQuestion
                            join personalInfo in _context.UserPersonalDetail on question.UserId equals personalInfo.UserId
                            select new NewQuestionVM
                            {
                                UserQuestionId = question.UserQuestionId,
                                Description = question.Description,
                                Title = question.Title,
                                Tags = question.Tag.Select(t => new QuestionTagViewModel
                                {
                                    SkillName = t.SkillTag.SkillName,
                                    SkillTagId = t.SkillTagId,
                                }).ToList(),
                                Voting = _context.UserQAVoting.Sum(x => x.Value),
                                Visitors = _context.QuestionVisitor.Where(av => av.QuestionId == question.UserQuestionId).Count(),
                                PostedBy = personalInfo.FirstName + " " + personalInfo.LastName,
                                UserPic = personalInfo.ProfileImage,
                                PostTime = question.PostTime,
                                HasVerifiedAns = question.HasVerifiedAns,
                            }).Take(10);
        if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(searchString))
        {
            questionList = questionList.Where(s => s.Description.Contains(searchString)
                            || s.Title.Contains(searchString));

        }
        @ViewBag.UName = HttpContext.Session.GetString("Name");
        int pageSize = 10;
        return View(new QuestionListVM { Questions = await PaginatedList<NewQuestionVM>.CreateAsync(questionList.AsQueryable(), page ?? 1, pageSize) });

    }
```

and here is the PaginatedList class.

```
    public class PaginatedList<T> : List<T>
{
    public int PageIndex { get; private set; }
    public int TotalPages { get; private set; }

    public PaginatedList(List<T> items, int count, int pageIndex, int pageSize)
    {
        PageIndex = pageIndex;
        TotalPages = (int)Math.Ceiling(count / (double)pageSize);

        this.AddRange(items);
    }

    public bool HasPreviousPage
    {
        get
        {
            return (PageIndex > 1);
        }
    }

    public bool HasNextPage
    {
        get
        {
            return (PageIndex < TotalPages);
        }
    }

    public static async Task<PaginatedList<T>> CreateAsync(IQueryable<T> source, int pageIndex, int pageSize)
    {
        var count = await source.CountAsync();
        var items = await source.Skip((pageIndex - 1) * pageSize).Take(pageSize).ToListAsync();
        return new PaginatedList<T>(items, count, pageIndex, pageSize);
    }

    internal static Task<string> CreateAsync<TEntity>(IQueryable<TEntity> queryable, int v, int pageSize) where TEntity : class
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}}
```

but i dont understand how is this giving such error. i would love to get some help.

Comment: You might gain insight by looking at the generated SQL. See here for some useful extensions to achieve that: https://gist.github.com/nour-s/3bbf9b2588faa6b849393639a8b39757

Comment: yes i tried it but i wasn't still working.